# Remove specific subviews (swift)

Tags: swift

Question: How Can i just remove all the subview of UIButton? if i remove all subviews, it will remove the cell title as well.

This is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let lblTitle : UILabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
    lblTitle.text = (deptId[indexPath.row] as? String)! + "     " + (deptDesc[indexPath.row] as? String)!
    var height:CGFloat = 0
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    if(indexPath == selectedIndexPath){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        for i in 0...deptProfile.count-1 {
            let deptmentProfile = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,44+height,400,41))
            deptmentProfile.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            height = height+41
            deptmentProfile.setTitle(deptProfile[i] as! String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            deptmentProfile.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            deptmentProfile.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
            deptmentProfile.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            deptmentProfile.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 40, 0, 0); //margin to the left
            cell.addSubview(deptmentProfile)
        }
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    } 
    return cell
}
```

Comment: "remove all the subview of UIButton?" You are adding a `UIButton` in your code, where are you removing it? Please be more elaborative in your question. What you are doing and what you are trying to do but which is not working for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try like this :

```
for view in subviews {
    if view is UIButton {
       view.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

NicolasMiari's suggest way:

```
for view in subviews  where view is UIButton{
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: This works too. But the `where` style is more Swift-y and takes less nesting.

Answer (score 1):

If your just wanna remove all subviews from deptmentProfile

```
for subview in deptmentProfile.subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

if you mean remove the subview which is type of UIButton, using where clause is a proper and elegant way

```
for subview in testButton.subviews where subview is UIButton {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: No, i don't want to remove all subviews. i want to remove subviews of uibutton only

Comment: deptmentProfile is UIButton, so my answer is to remove subviews of uibutton. Any problem？

Comment: Perhaps he means "Subviews that _are_ of type UIButton"? In that case, adding `where subview is UIButton` should do the trick.